# Inner Join Tables But Select From One Table Only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables which I join so that I may compare a field and extract records from one table where the field being compared is not in both tables:

```
Table A
---------
Comp   Val
111    327
112    234
113    265
114    865


Table B
-----------
Comp2   Val2
111     7676
112     5678
```

So what im doing is to join both tables on Comp-Comp2, then I wish to select all values from Table A for which a corrssponding Comp does not exist in Table B. In this case, the query should result in:

```
Result
---------
Comp   Val
113    265
114    865
```

Here is the query:

```
select * into Result from TableA
inner join TableB
on (TableB.Comp2 = TableA.Comp)
where TableB.Comp2 <> TableA.Comp
```

Problem is, it pulls values from both tables. Is there a way to select values from TableA alone without specifying the fields explicitly?

Comment: Like this: `TableA.*`

Comment: In these cases it is preferable to use `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want this, though:

```
select  *
    from TableA a
    where
        not exists (select b.Comp2 from TableB b where a.Comp1 = b.Comp2)
```

That will find all records in A that don't exist in B.

Answer (score 31):

Just prefix the `*` with the desired table name, like this:

```
select TableA.* into Result from TableA
inner join TableB
on (TableB.Comp2 = TableA.Comp)
where TableB.Comp2 <> TableA.Comp
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tblA a,tblB b 
WHERE a.comp <> b.comp
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do a **left join** and then just return rows that do **not** match:

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
    LEFT JOIN TableB
        ON TableA.Comp = TableB.Comp2
WHERE TableB.Comp IS NULL
```

You can restrict the columns return like this, but it is typically better to not user the *, but to name all of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

For me works like this. TABLE ARE FOR TESTS

```
select ov_item.*, ov.data_fecha from ov_item
inner join ov
on ov_item.id_ov = ov.id
where id_vendedor = 50 or id_tecnico = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.* FROM RMS_User A LEFT JOIN RMS_Department D ON A.DepartmentId = D.Id WHERE D.Identifier = 'ADMIN'